# How to make it impossible to press a button when it reaches the last element in the array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Please, help. How to make it impossible to press a button when it reaches the last element in the array. For some reason, it reaches the last element of the array, and you can also click once. And also when you click on the minus and it comes to the first element you can also click once and then button is disable.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ameli7777/po7qdwk8/2/

```
const totalCount = document.querySelector('.total-count');
const buttonMinus = document.querySelector('.btn-minus');
const buttonPlus = document.querySelector('.btn-plus');
const pointCount = document.querySelector('.point-count');

let point = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.05, 0.08, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.50, 0.80, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 20];
let i = 5;
let count;
pointCount.innerHTML = point[0];

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-plus')) {
        if(i !== point.length - 1) {
            i += 1;
            pointCount.innerHTML = point[i];
        } else {
            buttonPlus.classList.add('disable-btn');
        }
        buttonMinus.classList.remove('disable-btn');
    }
    if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-minus')) {
        if (i === 0) { 
            buttonMinus.classList.add('disable-btn');
        } else {
            i -= 1; 
            pointCount.innerHTML = point[i];
        }
        buttonPlus.classList.remove('disable-btn');
    };
    count = point[i] * 20;
    totalCount.innerHTML = "$" + count.toFixed(2);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using `if / else` condition which means you can either move through the array OR disable the button. This way, it is possible to do both actions at once:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-plus')) {
        if(i !== point.length - 1) {
            i += 1;
            pointCount.innerHTML = point[i];
        }
        if (i === point.length - 1) {
            buttonPlus.classList.add('disable-btn');
        }
        buttonMinus.classList.remove('disable-btn');
    }
    if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-minus')) {
        if (i !== 0) {
            i -= 1; 
            pointCount.innerHTML = point[i];
        }
        if (i === 0) { 
            buttonMinus.classList.add('disable-btn');
        }
        buttonPlus.classList.remove('disable-btn');
    };
    count = point[i] * 20;
    totalCount.innerHTML = "$" + count.toFixed(2);
});
```

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j0kczaLn/2/